# (JavaScript) How to return result from another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, function

[imagem printscreen ---------](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxA7V.png)

**Platform:** NodeJS

I have two roles in the nodejs project
I'm having trouble inserting the result of the **second** function into the **first** function.

> How to insert the result of the RUN function within the first function
> start (client)?

```
function start (client)
...
.sendText (message.from, 'Example' + result.rows + 'Text text')
...


function run ()
...
Console.log (result.rows);
...
```

### Full code

```
'use strict';
const venom = require('venom-bot');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

venom
.create()
.then((client) => start(client))
.catch((erro) => { console.log(erro); });

function start(client)
 {
  client.onMessage((message) =>
  { 
  if (message.body === 'Vendas' && message.isGroupMsg === false) 
     {    client
        .sendText(message.from, 'Example text' + result.rows + 'Etc etc') 
        .then((result) => {console.log('Result: ', result); }) 
        .catch((erro) => { console.error('Error when sending: ', erro); }); 
}});
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
async function run() {
  let connection;
  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
    const sql =`SELECT 'Testeee' FROM dual`;
    let result;
    result = await connection.execute(sql);
     Console.log(result.rows);
    
 } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
   
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making `start()` async either and apply `wait`.

```
async function start(client){
    const result = await run();

    // the rest of your code
}
```

In `run()` you let the method return the value.

```
async function run() {
   let connection;
   try {
      connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
      const sql =`SELECT 'Testeee' FROM dual`;
      return await connection.execute(sql);
} // rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
you have solved a big problem.

You would have more example, suggestions for
do this communication between functions?

Comment: First of all, I'd really appreciate if you could mark this answer as solution to your problem. Thanks in advance.   --- Unfortunately, each task has other things you have to be careful of. But a basic rule that is always true when you develop in Javascript is: "Always make sure whether a function call is synchronous or asynchronous. Because you can always call synchronous functions from async functions, but never the other way around, if you expect to wait for a/the return value.